# Networks not showing in graphite measurement (Fastnetmon + Influxdb)

Tags: influxdb, graphite, fastnetmon

I installed Fastnetmon community edition using this guide: https://fastnetmon.com/install/

I then continued on to this guide to create a database and display them in a dashboard: https://fastnetmon.com/docs/influxdb_integration/

*NOTE: I want to point out that Ionly used the first version of influxdb and not influxdb2 because influxdb2 doesn't seem to support graphite anymore. The guide in the second link that I sent will redirect you to install influxdb2.*

Everything went well except for one thing. The *networks* that I put in graphite is not appearing for some reason.

Screenshot from the guide:
[Screenshot from the guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fJJN.png)

Screenshot of my results: [Screenshot of my results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilZjj.png)

Networks is not appearing which means I cannot pull any data from it. Anyone has any idea why it is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

Update: I had it working after enabling the network counters in fastnetmon.conf file.